# Python: Variables do not seem to reassign in while loop + local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function, opencv, while-loop, global-variables

so I've been working on a little project in order to improve my skills with OpenCV in Python. 
But somehow I am struggling with my variables in a function.

This is my main code with a while loop. I basically want it to run a function for 3 times, which is given in another file and crops an given image.

```
croppedImage = [0] * len(urls)
while number < 3:
    message, croppedImage[number] = ImageProcessing.cropImage(path)
    print(bot+"Successfully cropped "+message)
    number += 1
```

My function looks like this. I somehow had to assign the coordinates for cropping the given image as global variables, since I received another error without doing so (*"local variable referenced before assignment"*). But with this code I am at least able to crop the first image successfully based on its colors.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def cropImage(path):
    global x_coordinate
    global y_coordinate
    global image_width
    global image_height
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_range = np.array([70, 14, 35])
    upper_range = np.array([125, 55, 36])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
    contours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
    result = img.copy()
    largest_area = 0
    for contour in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        if w > 650 and w < 750:
            area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
            if area > largest_area:
                largest_area = area
                (x_coordinate, y_coordinate, image_width, image_height) = (x, y, w, h)

    croppedImage = result[y_coordinate:y_coordinate+image_height, x_coordinate:x_coordinate+image_width]
    message = "[Width: "+str(image_width)+"] [Height: "+str(image_height)+"]"
    return message, croppedImage
```

Basically the code should crop given images, but somehow it only works on the first image. After the **X, Y, Width and Height** Variables have been assigned in the first run, the code does not update those variables in the second run from the while loop. So every image gets cropped to the same size, but I rather want the image to be cropped to the detected size (***image_width*** variable, as well as **image_height** variable stays same).

I have been trying to get it solved since days, but I don't get it working. Appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: Sometimes it doesnt even work and I only get a "NameError: name 'y_coordinate' is not defined" error.

Comment: `ImageProcessing.cropImage(path)` : in your while loop are you *sending* the same file path to the function on each iteration? In the function have you inspected other *variables*? Is `hsv` or `contours` or `mask` changing with each iteration of the while loop that calls it?

Comment: `if w > 650 and w < 750:` - have you inspected/tested to see if this condition has been satisfied?

Comment: @wwii The path is different everytime, that is not the problem. I will try if the other variables actually change, thanks for this suggestion

Comment: @wwii just tested it.. the hsv is definitely different, since it takes another source as image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably the placement of the assignment in the last line of this block:

```
   for contour in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        if w > 650 and w < 750:
            area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
            if area > largest_area:
                largest_area = area
                (x_coordinate, y_coordinate, image_width, image_height) = (x, y, w, h)
```

which is not neccessarily executed.

One solution could be:

```
(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, image_width, image_height) = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])
for contour in contours[1:]:
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            if w > 650 and w < 750:
                area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
                if area > largest_area:
                    largest_area = area
                    (x_coordinate, y_coordinate, image_width, image_height) = (x, y, w, h)
```

Comment: This somehow leads to the width and height being only 1px for every image

Comment: Try starting the loop at contours[0] even if that has been used to initialize the variables. _I.e._ `for contour in contours:` as in your original code.